# Boolean operations on segments of a same line

Tags: geometry, boolean-operations

I have been looking for some guidance on a geometry problem
I have 2 segments that lie on the same line and I want to clip both based on any of the boolean operations

```
Union, Intersection, Difference, Difference-Rev, Xor
```

The expected result should be a list of segments because cases can return 0,1 or 2 segments

in my current approach, I define a segment as a pair of 2 numbers (coordinates) on the same line

```
Segment 1 : (2,13)
Segment 2: (8,16)
```

my first step is make an array of sorted points

```
points = [2, 8, 13, 16]
```

second is iterate and label the points by their owner

```
Segment 1, Segment 2 or Both
```

Finally, I need to do  a selection given a boolean operation and the labels

But currently I'm stuck on the second step and I don't know how to find the labels and then do the selection given the boolean operation, any help ?

[image: Example Outputs Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put triplets `[coordinate, begin/end, segment number]` in the list.

Sort the list.

Walk through the list. At every point change a `code` adding or subtracting segment number. So `code=3` denotes segement intersection, `code=1` corresponds to the first segment only range.

Form resulting ranges depending on operation required and `code` change. Here I just enumerated operations in your list order.

I'm not sure what to do when end of one segment coinsides with beginning of another. Current sorting puts `end` before `begin`, so union will give two separate ranges. If needed, change sign of begin/end field and make `code -= p[1] * p[2]`

Python code:

```
def boolops(s1, s2, op):
    pts = [[s1[0], 1, 1], [s1[1], -1, 1],[s2[0], 1, 2],[s2[1], -1, 2]]
    pts.sort()
    #print(pts)
    res = []
    code = 0
    oldcode = 0
    start = -1
    for p in pts:
        code += p[1] * p[2]
        #print(oldcode, code)
        if op == 0:  # union
            if oldcode == 0 and code:
                start = p[0]
            elif oldcode and code == 0:
                res.append([start, p[0]])
        elif op == 1: #intersection
            if code == 3:
                start = p[0]
            elif oldcode == 3:
                res.append([start, p[0]])
        elif op == 2: #diff s1-s2
            if code == 1:
                start = p[0]
            elif oldcode == 1:
                res.append([start, p[0]])
        elif op == 3: #rev diff s2-s1
            if code == 2:
                start = p[0]
            elif oldcode == 2:
                res.append([start, p[0]])
        elif op == 4: #xor
            if code % 3 > 0:
                start = p[0]
            else:
                res.append([start, p[0]])
        oldcode = code
    return res


print(boolops([2,10],[5,12], 0)) 
print(boolops([2,5],[10,12], 0))

print(boolops([2,10],[5,12], 1)) 
print(boolops([2,5],[10,12], 1))

print(boolops([2,10],[5,12], 2))
print(boolops([2,5],[10,12], 2))

print(boolops([2,10],[5,12], 3))
print(boolops([2,5],[10,12], 3))

print(boolops([2,10],[5,12], 4))
print(boolops([2,5],[10,12], 4))

[2, 12]]   #union
[[2, 5], [10, 12]]
[[5, 10]]  #intersection
[]
[[2, 5]]  #diff
[[2, 5]]   
[[10, 12]] #revdiff
[[10, 12]]
[[2, 5], [10, 12]]  #xor
[[2, 5], [10, 12]]

#full coverage tests
print(boolops([2,5],[1,6], 0))
print(boolops([2,5],[1,6], 1))
print(boolops([2,5],[1,6], 2))
print(boolops([2,5],[1,6], 3))
print(boolops([2,5],[1,6], 4)

[[1, 6]]
[[2, 5]]
[]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

)